# empty array on getParsedBody

Tags: php, psr-7, mezzio

I have a `ServerRequestInterface $request` and when I call

`$body = $request->getBody()->getContents()`

it returns `{"email":"a@b.com","password":"password"}`, but `$request->getParsedBody()` returns an empty array[0].

This is a POST request.

Anyone know what might be going on here?

I'm using Zend Expressive if that matters (it shouldn't unless it's a bug).

`Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest`

Comment: BTW, I might be seriously misunderstanding how this works.

Comment: Are you setting the encoding to JSON?

Comment: Where would I do that?

Comment: Is the `content-type` of the request `application/json`?

Comment: also, don't forget to register `Zend\Expressive\Helper\BodyParams\BodyParamsMiddleware`.

Comment: Does content-type on the request actually get read?  I tried that, though, but I thought that was for the response.

Comment: yeah, it does. show us how did you register the middleware, and check the headers of the request.